# How to custom expression in Thymeleaf text template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the code using Thymeleaf as below:

```
Context context = new Context();
context.setVariable("name", "Thymeleaf");

String content = new TemplateEngine().process("Hi [(${name})]", context);
```

And Result

```
Hi Thymeleaf
```

Is it possible using `{{name}}` instead of `[(${name})]`? 
And How do it?

Comment: No, that's not possible... `[(${name})]` is a Thymeleaf expression and `{{name}}` is not.

Comment: Not possible, and what will you get if you remove that $ sign?

Comment: This is valid: `"Hi [[${{name}}]]"`. In my case I'm using a  `org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.StringTemplateResolver`. If you don't provide a conversion service, it just returns the string. See [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#data-conversion-formatting). Is this what you were asking about? Do you intend to use a Thymeleaf - or Spring - conversion service?

Comment: I want create `{{name}}` (prefix: '{{', suffix: '}}') as a Thymeleaf expression.
It mean

`String content = new TemplateEngine().process("Hi {{name}}", context);`

and expected result is `Hi Thymeleaf`.